# Will a 33" sink fit into a 35" wide kitchen cabinet

Tags: cabinets, kitchen-sink

Our cabinet maker accidentally built a 35" wide kitchen sink base cabinet instead of a 36" base ~ we only realized this several weeks after all cabinets were installed, and don't have time to redo everything. I have a 33" wide drop-in cast iron sink but the interior of the base cabinet is only 33.5" wide; is that wide enough?  I was informed by a sink manufacturer that I shouldn't put my 350 lb. sink into a 35" wide base cabinet due to the weight, and they recommend a 36"cabinet; they gave no explanation as to how one inch would make a difference; I need a better understanding as to why this would be an issue.

Comment: @Ruskes the OP said he didn't have the time for that and is asking if a 35" sink base vs. a 36" sink base would be an issue.  I dk, but maybe others do know.  A 350lb sink is very very heavy so it will need to be properly supported.  Again, I DK, but maybe others do.

Comment: 1/2 total clearance leave 1/4" clearance on each side.  that is tight but likely manageable.  Is the sink 100% 33.5" wide.  Maybe the tolerances on cast are loose and it is 33.5" on one end and 33.75 on the other.  You can always grind metal or even grind part of the cabinet and add re-enforcing.  weight isn't the issue.

Comment: Without details of the sink shape and fixing method and the frame any answer will be so general as to have little use.

Comment: About the only reason for it not supporting the weight, is if they think the supporting wood would need to be cut out too much, but usually there should be work arounds if the sink fits.

Comment: Knee-jerk "return it" comments are so not helpful, @Ruskes. RET, Why ask us and provide so little detail? Measure the thing and find out. We're of no use to you here.

Comment: 350 lbs? That sounds really, really heavy. A quick search found 130 lbs. for a Kohler 33" sink, and general sites saying 150 to 200 lbs.

Comment: The sink mfgr's statement seems really backwards to me. It strikes me that the _closer_ the vertical support is to the edge of the sink, the more sturdy the support will be. Imagine dropping a 350lb sink into a 60" wide cabinet with ~15" of clear span on either side? The whole counter top would start to sag, probably within minutes! Sounds like a bit of CYA to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You said drop in sink. That drops into a hole in the countertop. The countertop sits on top of your cabinets. Your sink will be supported by the countertop. I can see an  issue if the sink is wider than 33.5" then it won't fit into the cabinet. At 350 lbs. I doubt it's held in with clips, if it is I don't think you'll be able to install any on the sides. I would assume it's just held in place with caulk/silicone. If the sink manufacturer couldn't explain why on inch would be an issue then he was probably just reading off a script and doesn't really know. If the countertop is a solid surface and well supported you should have no issues. If there are any issues it will be with the width of the sink not the weight. Carefully measure the sink before cutting the countertop to make sure it will fit in the cabinet.

Comment: The sink is cast iron and will be installed on top of granite.   The 350 pound weight was what the customer service dept. gave us.  We'll do a mock-up to see if the fit is right.

Comment: Just contacted the manufacturer again ~ their comment about the base cabinet needing to support 350 lbs did not apply solely to the sink.  They meant to say the base cabinet must support a total of 350 lbs with granite countertop and misc. included.  The sink itself weighs less than 150 lbs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a test,

and build 33x33 wood frame with 2x2 or 2x4 and see how deep can it be inserted. (the depth of the sink)

Since you only have 1/4 inch space on all sides it is worth testing first before the 350 pound sink gets stuck.

Comment: I do hope you planned to say to have the sink upside down on a surface and let the frame down on it.  350 Pounds and 2x2s.

Comment: @crip659 Wrong, that would only test the inner opening of the frame, which is irrelevant in this case.